# Can't run my app after installing Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 120.2.4

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an android application which worked well with Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging version 71.1740.4
Once I upgraded to the latest version "120.2.4", and I upgraded all its dependencies, Google play e.t.c packages to their latest versions, Then I built the app, everything built well, but when I tried to run the app, I constantly get this error, even after updating each and every firebase or google package in my android project.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added :  Lcom/google/firebase/analytics/connector/AnalyticsConnectorImpl;

There is no additional message,
I search online for solutions, but I can't find one which works. Can someone help, please ?

Comment: When I update `Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging` version 120.2.4 and `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base` version 117.2.1, I have some problems, and I install `Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData` `Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser` `Xamarin.Google.Android.Material` and `Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.Co` to resolve these problem. I run project and have no problem.

Comment: Thanks, @CherryBu-MSFT I did that, I updated and installed the androidx packages. But I still have the issue which persists.

Comment: If you still have problem, please provide your sample at gtihub, I will download your sample to test.

Comment: The project is kind of closed source, Replecating it is kind of difficult, since it contains very old code. I'll try on a new project though

Comment: So you have any problem in new project?